# IntelliJ does not recognise Composer dependencies in PHP Project

Tags: php, intellij-idea, composer-php

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 15.0.2 but the IDE cannot "find" PHP classes provided via Composer despite them being within the `vendor` folder.

The IDE cannot see, for instance, `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` or `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` both of which are available within the `vendor` folder and the modules are listed individually as include paths within the IDE project settings.

The IDE does have the Composer plugin installed and configured. It also has PHPUnit configured as a plugin. The project does actually work as a web site, and if I run `phpunit` across the project independent of the IDE, it all works.

Suggestions welcome. I was wondering about PSR-0 roots but apparently none-new are found.

*Update 1: I have added `vendor` to the list of include paths per suggestion and gained nothing.*

*Update 2: If I open Project Structure > Modules, each of the composer-installed dependencies is listed as excluded deliberately. There's nothing mentioning this on the IntelliJ documentation that I've seen...*

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding the `vendor` folder to the list of **Include Paths**.

`File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Update include paths`

Referencing: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-include-paths.html